# Two possible triangle centers.

Tags: triangles, plane-geometry

1. For every point P in a triangular region T, consider the shortest and longest chords of T that pass thru P. Lets define 'Chord ratio(P)' = ratio between lengths of longest and shortest chords thru P.

For any triangle T, is there a unique point in its interior that is the minimum of the chord ratio? If so, is this point a known center of T?

2. Define Distance ratio(P) as the ratio between longest and shortest distances to boundary of T from P. Does this ratio too have a unique minimum point inside T? Is such a minimum a known center of T?

Note 1: Numerical experiments with general triangles strongly indicate that the above minimizing points do not coincide with the centroid, incenter or orthocenter.

Note 2: Instead of the ratios between a given pair of quantities, one can try to minimize the *difference* between them and that will give rise to more questions.

Comment: What approaches have you taken so far to answer these questions?

Comment: If $ABC$ is the triangle, your ratio will be equal to the min of $MA/MB, MB/MA, MC/MA,MA/MC,MB/MC,MC,MB$ Right ?

Comment: Please note maximizing the longest chord/shortest chord will give an infinite answer at the vertices, so we seek the minimum of this ratio.  And numerically, I could verify that the 'center' where chord ratio is minimized is not in general the incenter and this chord ratio center *seems* unique for triangles. This center can just as well be defined for general convex polygons and even for a square, it is not unique.

Comment: And note that a chord of a triangle thru an interior point P is a line segment that passes thru P and joins any two points on the triangle boundary, not only the vertices.